# sub menu on click CSS?

Tags: css

I want a menu like this:

[image]

When I click in message icon, show an menu with messages.

My problem is in CSS:

-> I want this open menu to be right below the MENU 2 (the same line) like in the attached image.

-> I don't know why .message is inline. I don't want .message menu to be inline.

How can I solve this problems?

css:

```
#menu{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 101;
 top:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bold;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
 min-width:50px;
 background:red;
}
#menu ul li{
 display:inline;   
 border:1px solid #fff;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.message{ 
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li>MENU 1</li>
      <li class="clickclass">MENU 2</li>

      <div class="message">
         <ul>
            <li><a href=#>item1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>item2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>item3</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>item4</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>     

      <li>MENU 3</li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p8h4ow1m/2/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot place a div element between two li elements.

Comment: so, what is the best way to do the menu I want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the markup is invalid and the structure requested cannot be created using this method.

Comment: @RickJoe [Here is an updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/p8h4ow1m/4/)

Comment: if I asked is because I need help with this, if it is invalid why you instead of say it is invalid just not help me with a valid one?

Comment: thank you @sdgluck ! now my html is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an almost perfect toggle menu using `checkbox` the structure you wanted cannot be created using css alone with your html so i changed it

```css
#click{
    width:200px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    height:40px;
  top:10px;
}

label{
    display:block;
    background:lightgrey;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

label ul{
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-type:none;
}

label ul li{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

label .hidden{
    height:0;
}

#click:checked + label .hidden{
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="click" />
<label>
    <ul>
        <li>Click Me!</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href=#>item1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>item2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>item3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=#>item4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should not place anything other than an `<li>` as a child of a list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`). Move your child menu into the menu item that it is related to:

```
<li class="clickclass">
    MENU 2

    <ul class="message">
        <li><a href=#>item1</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>item2</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>item3</a></li>
        <li><a href=#>item4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

2) Make each `<li>` be `position: relative` so that the child menu is positioned relative to its parent:

```
#menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;   
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

3) Position the child menu to the very-left of its parent (I also removed the padding):

```
.message { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Here is an updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/p8h4ow1m/4/).

Comment: @sdgluck hey great ans .just 1 thing i was curious about in your fiddle why the click on click class is not smooth.i tried to find but couldn't figure out.if you can explain will be great.

Comment: @imGaurav What do you mean _smooth_? Animated? There is no animation because none has been declared. You could add an animation yourself through jQuery or CSS3 animations.

Comment: @sdgluck not talking about the animation buddy , if you hove click class li you can see , when my cursor is default/arrow like no matter how much i click menu just wont show , it shows up when my cursor turns into auto ,so  why is that

Comment: @imGaurav You are able to display the sub-menu only when you click directly on the `<li>` element. [Here is updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/p8h4ow1m/5/) that should demonstrate this by applying the `cursor: pointer` style to all `<li>` elements.